# Requesting LinkedIn OAuth Access Token Fails with 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: linkedin-api

I get a 500 Internal Server Error status code from the [LinkedIn Oauth API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow#step-3-exchange-authorization-code-for-an-access-token) when requesting an access token through the https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken endpoint. I sent the request through Postman:
[image]

Some of the response headers are:

```
X-FS-UUID: e55c91c29d42be1500c2b829062b0000
X-Frame-Options: sameorigin
X-LI-UUID: 5VyRwp1CvhUAwrgpBisAAA==
X-Li-Fabric: prod-lor1
X-Li-Pop: afd-prod-esv5
X-Li-Proto: http/1.1
```

The [LinkedIn API docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/api-guide/concepts/error-handling#500-internal-server-error) explain that this 500 Internal Server Error status code means that LinkedIn is experiencing an internal error.

How can I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

All the key values should be sent as query params, and also remove code_verifer.

I am using the following request to fetch access Token

```
https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code&code=[CODE]&redirect_uri=https://getpostman.com/oauth2/callback&client_id=[CLIENT_ID]&client_secret=[CLIENT_SECRET]
```

Comment: This sounds weird. If this worked, it would be a violation of RFC 6749. The specification requires that requests to a token endpoint use HTTP *POST* method. Note that code_verifier is required if the corresponding authorization request includes code_challenge, which is written in RFC 7636.

Comment: Great point @TakahikoKawasaki -- while LinkedIn supports these requests today, they have been marked for deprecation.